# Como dar replace RegExp em div editável usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Eu tenho uma `div` editável onde capturo o todo texto dentro dela. Dai quero que em cada ocorrência de **determinada palavra** essa palavra seja substituida por outra. Bem simples.

O código que tentei não funcionou. Ele em si funciona só que a saída não funciona (que no caso é a própria entrada). Mas se for colocado num `alert()` por exemplo, funciona.

JS

```
    function teste(){
        var campo = document.getElementById('editorid').textContent;
        var docrg = /palavra/g; // procurar por 'palavra' sem ignorar case
        campo.replace(docrg, "outrapalavra"); // replace 'palavra' por 'outrapalavra'
    }
    document.getElementById('botao').addEventListener('click',teste,false);
```

HTML

```
    <div id="editorid" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <button id="botao">clica</button>
```

CSS (opcional so pra mostrar borda)

```
    #editorid{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
    }
```

Nota: Esse problema é apenas um módulo de um editor de texto que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Isto é bem simples se quiseres fazer somente quando se clicar no boão. Para fazer _on the fly_ é bem mais dificil, por causa do cursor basicamente. Estava a preparar uma resposta para fazer em tempo real quando se escregve (_on the fly_). Se quiseres só quando se carrega no botão diz :)

Comment: Deixei uma resposta com a versão simples. Explico melhor daqui a pouco. Esta época natalícia deixa pouco tempo livre :)

Comment: Faltou atribuir/atualizar o valor de campo. Ja resolvi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

Acho que a maior parte do código é fácil de compreender exeto a ExpReg.

`(palavra\-chave)(?!<)` em partes seria:

`()` - grupo para capturar texto
`palavra-chave` - o texto que queremos capturar onde escapei o `-` que em regex pode significar *entre* "a" e "c". (neste caso acho que não seria necessário, mas por hábito coloco).
`(?!<)` - isto quer dizer que o que estava antes não pode ser seguido de `<`. Coloquei esse caractere pois assim uma nova tag `<span>` por exemplo irá impedir a verificação.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var editavel = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');
    var novoConteudo = '<span class="format">palavra-chave</span>';
    editavel.innerHTML = editavel.innerHTML.replace(/(palavra\-chave)(?!<)/g, novoConteudo);
});
```

```css
.format {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
span.format {
    color: #aad;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>texto texto texto palavra-chave. texto palavra-chave, texto texto.</p>
</div>
<button>Mudar!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que está faltando uma atribuição nessa linha:

```
campo.replace(docrg, "outrapalavra"));
```

Ficando assim:

```
var aux = campo.replace(docrg, "outrapalavra");
```

Ou também pode ser o parêntese adicional na primeira instrução citada...

Comment: Agradeço a reposta mas eu não quero atribuir e sim chamar e não é o parêntese: só errei na pergunta.

Comment: O método replace retorna uma string. Se você não atribui o valor a algo, é retorno inutilizado.